# Unknown type name gcc

Tags: compiling, make, source-code

I'm trying to compile this source code http://nrg.cs.ucl.ac.uk/mptcp/mptcp_userland_0.1.tar.gz and I'm getting `unknown type name 'u8'` among other types (u_int, u_char, u_long....etc)

I have Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and gcc version 4.6.3

How to solve this issue?

Thank you

Comment: Have you installed the `-dev` and `-dbg` packages?

Comment: What are the exact name of these packages?

Comment: I am not too sure, I assume the generic `dev` and `dbg` packages for gcc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue by using typedef http://www.gnu.org/software/gnu-c-manual/gnu-c-manual.html#The-typedef-Statement

I added this `typedef unsigned u8;` to the beginning of the files I had errors in

You can find the current known integer data types here http://www.gnu.org/software/gnu-c-manual/gnu-c-manual.html#Integer-Types

Comment: This is a seriously dangerous advice and will likely cause all kinds of disaster. u8 is supposed to be defined as a 8-bit unsigned integer. "unsigned"  is just an unsigned int, which will likely be 32 or 64 bits depending on your architecture.